# Has word any of unaccepted chars?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

please, I have an array of unaccepted characters and I want if unknown word or sentence contains any of this characters. If now, I can add it to my `words` array

I have the code:

```js
// Define dictionary
let words = []

// Unaccepted characters
const unacceptedChars = [' ', '-', ',', '.']

let word = 'blue world'

if(!word.includes(unacceptedChars)) {
  console.log('This sentence doesn\'t contain any of unaccepted chars and could be used')
} else {
  console.log('Sentence can\'t be used')
}
```

The result is
`This sentence doesn't contain any of unaccepted chars and could be used`
which is wrong because word contains a space which is unaccepted character.

If I edit the code to

```js
// Define dictionary
let words = []

// Unaccepted characters
const unacceptedChars = [' ']

let word = 'blue world'

if(!word.includes(unacceptedChars)) {
  console.log('This sentence doesn\'t contain any of unaccepted chars and could be used')
} else {
  console.log('Sentence can\'t be used')
}
```

all works OK. Result is `Sentence can't be used`

Please, how I look in array in Javascript? I tried find the answer but I didn't found yet. Thanks for any advice

Comment: You cannot pass an array to [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). You should always read the documentation before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `includes` with array as parameter

the properly way is

```
try {
  unacceptedChars.forEach(char => {
    if(word.includes(unacceptedChars)) {
      Throw new Error('Sentence can\'t be used')
    }
  })
  console.log('This sentence doesn\'t contain any of unaccepted chars and could be used')
} catch(error => {
  console.error(error.message)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for inspiration to all. My finally solution is

```js
let words = []
const unacceptedChars = [' ', '-', '.', ',']
let newWord = $(this).text()
for (let i = 0; i < unacceptedChars.length; i++) {
  if (newWord.includes(unacceptedChars[i])) {
    allowedWord = false
    break
  }
}
if (allowedWord) words.push(newWord)
```

Thanks again to all